# Can i forward torrent packages from UDP/TCP peers to WebRTC peers using Webtorrent?

Tags: node.js, torrent, webtorrent

[Webtorrent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webtorrent)
[Webtorrent-hybrid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webtorrent-hybrid)

WebTorrent uses TCP/UDP to talk to other torrent clients, but using webtorrent-hybrid it can connect to all type of peers including WebRTC.

My question is if it's possible to forward the torrent packages from UDP/TCP peers to WebRTC peers using a nodejs app.
I don't want the nodejs app to download the whole torrent and then seed it to the WebRTC peers,
I want to somehow forward the UDP/TCP packages to the WebRTC peers.

Comment: So a tcp/udp proxy to WebRTC? Sure, why not? Just code it.

Comment: @Marc i would if i knew how... Maybe you can point me towards something that can help me get started?